# Actions on Bernoulli space have almost the same orbits

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, group-actions, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

> Let $(\mathbb{B}, \nu)$ be the binary space with probability measure $\nu(0) = \nu(1) = \frac{1}{2}$. The map $T : \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is defined as left addition with carry, i.e. if $x = (1, \ldots, 1, 0, x_k, \ldots)$ then $T(x) = (0, \ldots, 0, 1, x_k, \ldots)$. This map is a measure preserving Borel isomorphism. We can define two actions on the product space $(\mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}, \nu^{\otimes \mathbb{N}})$ as follows:
>
> - $\mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}} \curvearrowright \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ through componentwise addition modulo 2.
> - $\mathbb{Z} \curvearrowright \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ through $k \cdot x := T^k(x)$.
>
> Show that these actions are orbit equivalent, in other words, there exists a Borel isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is measure preserving and satisfies $\varphi(\mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}} \cdot x) = \mathbb{Z} \cdot \varphi(x)$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

I'm pretty stumped on this problem. If I'm not mistaken the orbit $\mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}} \cdot x$ should be the entire space $\mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ itself. Since $\varphi$ is supposed to be an isomorphism I assume this means $\mathbb{Z} \cdot \varphi(x) = \mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as well. However the former seems to be a countable set, while the latter isn't? Is there something obvious I'm seeing wrong here? This problem is taken from the paper [A. Ioana's lecture notes "Orbit Equivalence of Ergodic Group Actions"](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eaioana/orbit%20equivalence.pdf), Exercise 1.21.

**Edit:** So I thought of a potential solution, but I'm not sure I can take it all the way to its end, so here goes. For any $x \in \mathbb{B}^\mathbb{N}$, it seems clear on one hand that $\mathbb{B}^\mathbb{N} \cdot x = \mathbb{B}^\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, the set $\mathbb{Z} \cdot x$ contains all sequences that eventually have the same tail end as $x$, in other words it contains all the following sets:

$$
\begin{align}
\{x_0\} \times \{x_1\} \times \{x_2\} &\times \cdots \\
\mathbb{B} \times \{x_1\} \times \{x_2\} &\times \cdots \\
\mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \times \{x_2\} &\times \cdots \\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$

Hence if we define the Borel sets $Z_k = \mathbb{B}^k \times \{x_k\} \times \{x_{k+1}\} \times \cdots$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows from $Z_k \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \cdot x$ that $\bigcup^\infty_{k=0} Z_k \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \cdot x$. At this point I'd use the measure of the union as a lower bound for the measure of $\mathbb{Z} \cdot x$ but I now realize that's not as obvious as it first looked.